# How to call stored procedure from informix in datastage

Tags: datastage

Can you help me please? I have to call with job a stored procedure located in an Informix database (stored procedure with 4 parameters) and after store the data generated by stored procedure in a SQL Server database. Please tell me how to call this stored procedure (stored procedure stage do not support informix). Thanks in advance

Comment: please share your research and progress

Comment: Have you checked the Informix CLI Stage? The documentation mentions Stored Procs explicitly: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.informix.doc/topics/c_cinfxref_Functionality_of_Informix_CLI_Stages.html